# Redireccionar input do Flex para uma string

Tags: c, sintaxe, analise-léxica

Boas,

Eu tenho um ficheiro flex e uma rotina em C para verificar a escrita de textos.

Tenho andado a testar no command-prompt usando `test < inputFile`
O que eu queria agora era poder indicar no meu ficheiro em C um parâmetro (uma string) que depois ele verificasse (em vez de ser do stdin).

Como é que posso adicionar isso?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode passar o arquivo por argumento.

./teste inputFile

É para isso mesmo que serve o argc e argv da função main.
int main(int argc, char **argv)

argc é o número de parâmetros recebidos.
No exemplo acima, argc seria 1.

argv contém os argumentos em si.
No exemplo acima, argv[0] deve acessar o inputFile.

Comment: Sim, o meu problema é que isto depois é para integrar num programa de C# como uma DLL, portanto passar por argumento não me serve. 
(Ou serve e eu não estou a ver como?)

Comment: Desculpa @RodrigoGuiotti, por acaso isso pode ajudar, mas preciso de saber: como é que depois eu podia dizer que o inputFile era o novo input para o lex?

Comment: Não sei se entendi seu problema então... vamos ver.
O programa em C e em C# estão rodando?

Se estiverem você precisará decidir como será a comunicação entre os dois processos.
Pode ser por arquivo ou pela interface de rede local.

Dependendo do sistema operacional, pode ter um jeito melhor.

Comment: O programa em C# está a funcionar perfeitamente.
Depois fiz uma rotina em C que também funciona bem.

Agora o que eu queria era adicionar ao programa em c# uma dll para aceder às funções em c (mas isto não é o objectivo desta pergunta)

E depois enviar a string como parâmetro para a função em C e ai correr a verificação lexical. 

(deu para perceber?)

Comment: Nesse caso, parece que o programa em C# vai chamar seu programa em C. Quando o C# decidir a string, ele pode fazer uma chamada de sistema, tipo:
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\\Windows\\teste.exe inputFile");

Não?

Comment: Preferia não fazer assim.
Não há maneira de alterar o ficheiro lex ou a minha rotina c para ler directamente duma string? (e não de um ficheiro)

Comment: Para os dois programas usarem a mesma string, só usando memória compartilhada.

Comment: É possível converter para dll o código em C se este for gerenciado. Use dllexport para expor as funções que você quer acessar no C#.

Se o código for simples, talvez seja melhor copiar e colar em C# e corrigir o que não for suportado.

Answer (score 0):

O Flex lê os dados a partir da variável `yyin`, que é do tipo arquivo ou ficheiro.

Por padrão, essa variável está associada a entrada `STDIN`.

Você pode associar essa variável a outro arquivo ou ficheiro (ex: em um parâmetro) através do comando `yyin = fopen("nome_do_arquivo.zzz", "r");`.

Segue um exemplo, extraído do manual do Flex:

```
main( argc, argv )
{
   int argc;
   char **argv;

   if ( argc > 0 ) 
       yyin = fopen( argv[0], "r" );
   else
       yyin = stdin;

   yylex();
}
```

Caso a função esteja em uma `DLL`, você pode enviar o nome do arquivo como parâmetro da função. Exemplo:

```
__attribute__ ((dllexport)) int funcao_da_dll(const char *nome_arquivo)
{
    yyin = fopen(nome_arquivo, "r" );
    yylex();
}
```

Para mais referências (no ítem `THE GENERATED SCANNER`):

[FLEX](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/flex/manpage.html)

Comment: Hum isto ajuda-me ;) vou ver como consigo alterar isto para ser para uma string e não um file (nem que tenha de criar um ficheiro e depois destrui-lo.
Obrigado

Comment: @J.Pinto: retirei o comentário, pois as funções que eu indiquei não são compatíveis com o ambiente Windows

Comment: Sim eu vi @Gomiero, pois, eu estou a tentar ligar tudo, porque tenho de juntar isto a um programa em C#. Assim que o tiver conseguido fazer posto aqui uma resposta com o que fiz e atribuo a solução ou a si ou ao Rodrigo, consoante a que me tiver ajudado mais

Comment: Mais uma dica que pode ajudar (em inglês):  [Multiple Input Buffers](http://flex.sourceforge.net/manual/Multiple-Input-Buffers.html), e no SOen, tem um exemplo: [how to use yy_scan_string in lex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907847/how-to-use-yy-scan-string-in-lex) ou [String input to flex lexer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/780676/string-input-to-flex-lexer)